# ADS192R respiration rate detection

Tags: adc, analog, biopotential

In SBAA181 - Respiration Rate Measurement Based on Impedance Pneumography (page 8/11), what is the purpose of having potential divider of 10ME (R1=R2)?

[image]

the reference of these resistors are R84,R85,R86,R87.

Kindly explain its significance in the circuit..

Comment: For reference, this is http://www.ti.com/product/ads1298r and app note http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbaa181/sbaa181.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They provide an extremely high impedance bias voltage, so the DC component of voltage present at IN1P is centered around the middle of the analog supply range. This is necessary to set the DC point for the measurements made by the ADC.

As you can see, it's only AC-coupled to the rest of the circuit; the various capacitors make sure of that. They are there to prevent DC current flowing in the patient under measurement.